# Java ModelMapper -Failed to convert java.util.List to java.util.List

Tags: java, modelmapper

I am using the Java ModelMapper library to map DTOs to ORM `@Entity` objects. I have the following test set up:

```
    public class MapperTest {

    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper mapper;

    @Autowired
    private TicketRepository ticketRepo;

    @Test
    public void testTicket() {
        Ticket ticket = ticketRepo.findById(4).get();

        TicketDTO dto = mapper.map(ticket, TicketDTO.class);
        assertThat(dto.getEquipmenDescription()).isEqualTo(ticket.getEquipment().getDescription());
        assertThat(dto.getEquipmentNotes()).isEqualTo(ticket.getEquipmentNotes());
        assertThat(dto.getId()).isEqualTo(ticket.getId());
        assertThat(dto.getNotes()).isEqualTo(ticket.getNotes());
        assertThat(dto.getOracleID()).isEqualTo(ticket.getOracleID());
        assertThat(dto.getPropertyID()).isEqualTo(ticket.getPropertyID());
        assertThat(dto.getNotes().size()).isEqualTo(ticket.getNotes().size());

        for (TicketNoteDTO note : dto.getNotes()) {
            assertThat(note.getId()).isNotEqualTo(0);
            assertThat(note.getIssueDate()).isNotNull();
            assertThat(note.getUserUserName()).isNotEmpty();
        }
    }

}
```

This fails with the following error:

```
org.modelmapper.MappingException: ModelMapper mapping errors:

1) Converter org.modelmapper.internal.converter.CollectionConverter@501c6dba failed to convert java.util.List to java.util.List.
```

The following are my Entity and corresponding DTOs. Getters and setters are omitted for brevity.

Ticket

```
   @Entity
    @Table(name = "ticket")
    public class Ticket {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private int id;

        @Column(name = "equipment_notes")
        private String equipmentNotes;

        @Column(name = "is_open")
        private boolean isOpen;

        @Column(name = "oracle_id")
        private String oracleID;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "equipment_id")
        private EquipmentCategory equipment;

        @Column(name = "property_id")
        private String propertyID;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ticket")
        private List<TicketNote> notes = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

TicketNote (getters and Setters omitted for brevity)

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "ticket_note")
    public class TicketNote {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private int id;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "ticket_id")
        private Ticket ticket;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
        private AppUser user;

        @Column(name = "issue_date")
        private LocalDate issueDate;

        @Column(name = "oracle_contact")
        private String oracleContact;

        @Column(name = "issue_resolved")
        private boolean issueResolved;
}
```

TicketDTO

```
    public class TicketDTO {

        private int id;
        private String equipmentNotes;
        private boolean isOpen;
        private String oracleID;
        private String equipmenDescription;
        private String propertyID;
        private List<TicketNoteDTO> notes = new ArrayList<>(); 
}
```

TicketNoteDTO

```
public class TicketNoteDTO {

        private int id;
        private String userUserName;
        private LocalDate issueDate;
        private String oracleContact;
        private boolean issueResolved;
    }
```

I have some experience with the ModelMapper library, but I am not sure what the issue is. Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks.